# Accelerometer not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

Good day all, I'm trying to make an android app using Phonegap. I want to update the values every 1 sec. For some reason I'm not getting any values.  I'm using `Phonegap-2.9.0`, my Device is `HTC Wildfire S`, android version `2.3.5`. Here is my code,

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
document.addEventListener("deviceready", loaded, false);

function loaded() {
 startWatch();
}

function startWatch() {

 var options = { frequency: 1000 };

 watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);
}


function stopWatch() {
 if (watchID) {
    navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(watchID);
    watchID = null;
 }
}

function onSuccess(acceleration) {
 var element = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
 element.innerHTML = 'Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + '<br />' +
                    'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + '<br />' +
                    'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + '<br />' +
                    'Timestamp: '      + acceleration.timestamp + '<br />';
}

function onError() {
 alert('onError!');
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="accelerometer"></div>
</body>
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Your help would be really appreciable. Tnx.

Comment: are you getting some error on logcat?

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I get this error, not sure if its even an error,
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment at file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:981

Answer (score 0):

Solution try this you must have in the scope of a function `onDeviceReady()` this method `watchAcceleration()` to work
according to https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion/blob/110b27671f454fcc28f7f642d55874ab0a7fe4a1/doc/index.md

> Access is via a global navigator.accelerometer object.
>   Although the object is attached to the global scoped navigator, it is not available until after the deviceready event.

In your case `loaded()` is `onDeviceReady()`
and another aspect you don't have function `init()`
you have only

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", loaded, false);
```

put into function `init()` this your line `document.addEventListener("deviceready", loaded, false);`
and then `<body onload="init()">`
so I mean add attribute onload with value `init()` to your `<body>` tag placed on the bottom of your code